# Map current array with values by index from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's imagine I have to arrays:

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const array2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

array2.map((elem, index) => {
  // Looking here to return the value from array1 by index
});
```

From `array2` I am looking to return values from `array1`, by the index position, but just in the range 1 -10. The idea is that it should go in a kind of circle where the start value is 1 and end value is 10.

The expected output for the above example is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

More examples of how it should work:

- Index 1 from array2 -> return 1 from array1
- Index 10 from array2 -> return 10 from array1
- Index 12 from array2 -> return 2 from array1
- Index 20 from array2 -> return 10 from array1
- Index 999 from array2 -> return 9 from array1
- Index 1225 from array2 -> return 5 from array1

Comment: @trincot -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: You don't need two arrays to achieve this, you could just use the modulo operator for the length of array1 to perform the wraparound. i.e. ` array1[index % (len(array1) + 1)]`.

Comment: @Exari, added that info to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the remainder operator (`%`):

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const array2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

const result = array2.map((elem, index) => array1[index % array1.length]);


console.log(result);
```

You really don't need to *have* `array2`, which provides no information other than its length -- the zeroes are not relevant. So given just the length, it could be as follows:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const length = 15;

const result = Array.from({length}, (elem, index) => array1[index % array1.length]);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was all ready to nitpick with "Thats the modulo operator" and MDN calls it the remainder operator. I feel my worldview has been shattered :D

Comment: Yeah, @Jamiec, I was there before :-) The difference is relevant though for negative values. `-2 modulo 3 == 1`, but in JavaScript `-2 % 3 == -2`

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need two arrays to achieve this. You could use the modulo operator to perform 'wrap around' like lookups.

For example:

```
 array1[index % (array1.length)]
```

if you absolutely need the info in a second array, something like this would achieve the desired result:

```
  array2.forEach((_, index) => array2[index] = array1[index % (array1.length)]);
```

Comment: For that current example, yes, you're right. I used to put 2 arrays, cause in my real case, I have 2 arrays. That's why! Thanks!